# Having Error in Textview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am unable to solve the error and i have spent more than hour to resolve it but can't identify.

mainactivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, mDrawerListItems));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int editedPosition = position + 1;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Selected item" + editedPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        });
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();

            }
        };
        /*drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);*/

    }
```

And i am getting an error in log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:931)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

And i am using android Studio tool

Would be helpful if someone suggest me where i am wrong.

Comment: Please do paste full log. Here line number were the error occurred is not present in your log. That would help in understanding the issue. But from the error it is clear that somewhere you have use linear layout and u are trying to assign it to Textview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go wrong over here

```
 mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, mDrawerListItems));
```

Just change it

```
 mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list_item, mDrawerListItems));
```

Supply your `R.layout.activity_list_item layout` to `ArrayAdapter`